# EditText field gets an incorrect output

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-studio, android-bundle, fragmentmanager

So, I have this testing app where I am trying to have two fragments communicate via `MainActivity`. After some research, I have managed to pass data from `MainFragment` to `FragmentTwo`. However, whenever I pass in string value from the `MainFragment`, I get a message saying

> "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{cce883f VFED .....
>   app:id/editText}"

I couldn't find what the problem was for this case. Please help.
BTW I know how to use intents and that they are much more flexible(sometimes) than fragments are but this is just so that I know how far I can go with Fragments.

Here's my MainActivity

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class    MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,                     MainFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener {

private String dataReceiver;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}

@Override
public void sendInformations(String message) {
    FragmentTwo fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(fragmentTwo.DATA_RECEIVE, message);
    fragmentTwo.setArguments(args);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragmentTwo)
            .commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.frag_one) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new FragmentOne()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.frag_two) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new FragmentTwo()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.frag_three) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new FragmentThree()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.frag_four) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new FragmentFour()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.main_frag) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MainFragment()).commit();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

MainFragment class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainFragment extends Fragment   {
OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;
Button sendData;


public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
    public void sendInformations(String message);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);


    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);

    final EditText userInput = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    sendData = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);


    sendData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.button) {
                mCallback.sendInformations(userInput.toString());
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

FragmentTwo class

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {
final static String DATA_RECEIVE = "data_receive";
TextView textView;
String input;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.data_receiver2);
    savedInstanceState = getArguments();
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        input = savedInstanceState.getString(DATA_RECEIVE);
    }
    textView.setText(input);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

Oh, and the message I get is when I run the app, type into the textfield, and press the button, I get the weird message. I would appreciate if anyone can tell me what is causing the weird output..

If this is a bug, which I had noticed in some cases that were relevant, is it because I deprecated the v7.Fragment & v7.FragmentManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically passing the EditText as a string in place of the EditText value.

In your MainFragment change `mCallback.sendInformations(userInput.toString());` to `mCallback.sendInformations(userInput.getText().toString());`

```
sendData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         if (v.getId() == R.id.button) {
             mCallback.sendInformations(userInput.getText().toString());
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you vey much. That seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: Cheers! Glad I could help.